# Recover a deleted file NetBeans 8.0.2?

Tags: netbeans-8

I accidently deleted a script file under my folder: "Includes" when trying to replace the folder with another one to change the appearence of the page..

Is there a way of recovering these?

Comment: Is "local history" enabled? If yes, you can right click on the folder inside the project window and choose "History -> Revert deleted"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! you sir may add an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is "local history" enabled? If yes, you can right click on the folder inside the project window and choose "History -> Revert deleted"